# How to run "rails s" using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I am  following a long a tutorial and get the following output when I run `rails s`. I am able to use `rail new`.

```
    Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

    Options:
          [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]              # Skip namespace (affects only     isolated applications)
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                          # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                             # Default: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                  # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                  # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                             # Default: sqlite3
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]                  # Don't create a Gemfile
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                          # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                      # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]      # Skip Action Mailer files
      [--skip-action-mailbox], [--no-skip-action-mailbox]    # Skip Action Mailbox gem
      [--skip-action-text], [--no-skip-action-text]          # Skip Action Text gem
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]      # Skip Active Record files
      [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]    # Skip Active Storage files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                        # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]        # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]              # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                    # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                    # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]            # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]            # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                        # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]          # Skip system test files
      [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]                # Skip bootsnap gem
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                                  # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                              # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                                # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                    # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                    # Don't run bundle install
  --webpacker, [--webpack=WEBPACK]                           # Preconfigure Webpack with a particular framework (options: react, vue, angular, elm, stimulus)
      [--skip-webpack-install], [--no-skip-webpack-install]  # Don't run Webpack install

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

    Example:
        rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

        This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

I read other questions regarding this but none fixed the problem.

I am in the `apps` directory, and here's the `ls` output:

```
config.ru  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  Rakefile  README.md
```

I saw other answers mentioning a script folder, but I do not have a script folder.

I also tried: `rake rails:update:bin` and get this output:

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/ec2-user/workspace/basic/config/application
/home/ec2-user/workspace/basic/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/ec2-user/workspace/basic/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace
```

Comment: Look closely at the tutorial. It's `rails s` not `rails -s` Your title has it right, but your description does not. I suspect you typed in `rails -s` from the looks of it.

Comment: This looks like it was a mistake on my end, I typed rails s and get same output.

Comment: `rails s` shouldn't produce the help (usage) screen since it's a valid `rails` command. That seems unlikely. In fact, the screen you show looks like it's the result of a malformed `rails new` command since it's describing `rails new`. If it really does, try `rails server` (`rails s` is short for `rails server`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect in project folder and then run `rails s` Probably you are one folder back. You should see app/ bin/ config/ when you type `ls` on command line.